# How to install SQL in IntelliJ 2016.2.5 & How to create a project SQL IntelliJ

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I have **IntelliJ 2016.2.5** and want to work with SQL. I went to configure -> Plugins -> Searched: SQL[image]

it seemed that it has been installed but when I click *creat proj.*
[image]

I dont know where I can start to create a SQL project? I found "Intellij Plattform Plug in" and once I click SQL it says
[image]
I dont understand. Can someone help me?

**--> Please tell me step by step.**

Comment: you can't create a 'sql' project ... sql is a language to manipulate databases. So if you want to learn sql, you need to install a database like mysql, postgresql or sql server

Comment: strange! Then check this youtube link? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNuCEzd9smY HOW did he do that? Didnt he created a SQL file and simple coding it?..

Comment: I think he used the plugin you downloaded to open a connection to a database and manipulate it. I don't really use intellij that often so can't tell it for sure, but that's how it looks to me

Comment: ..... and do you know how exactly?

Comment: your first picture : on the right side you have an explanation about what you downloaded => " this plugin enales handling information stored in a relational database"

Comment: this is not really helping.. . Do I need to install SDK?

Comment: depends on the project you want to create, if you have intellij i assume you'll mainly work with java (?). Do you already installed java developpement kit ? if yes then select it in 'project sdk' field, if no you'll have to download one

Comment: Please read [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html). Once you've done that, create any kind of project, then add SQL files to it.

Comment: @BastienJansen Hell no. I have No time to read the docs. It was too complicated. I know the answers..

Comment: @mJehanno no I dont need to do with Java or other language.. Check my answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer **(This is for NEWBIE/ BEGINNERS SQL for IntelliJ)**:

Fallow my steps:

1. first of all you need a simple .sql file. You can create it by notepad and then save as .sql
2. Check if your IntelliJ SQL plug in is installed
   [image]
3. You need to install MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ ***(this is for windows!!)*** Remember! You username and Password and your install must be succeed. If it's not working then IntelliJ cant communicate SQL server.
4. Create Empty project
5. click database [image]
6. Click plus.. [image]
7. **YOU MUST CLICK "DOWNLOAD MISSING FILES"** [image]
8. First you go Database and **Ctrl + Space** 
   [image]
9. it pop up a window and you here you must enter your MySQL user and password
   [image]
10. then you can find **your** file..
    [image]
11. You must enter (again) your user and password SQL and you must TEST if its working before you click ok
    [image]
12. Now there, type anything you want and press run [image: enter image descriptionhere]
13. **And here is the result.**
    [image]

**Happy Coding**.